# Flying from Toronto to Mumbai via Newark

Tags: indian-citizens, b1-b2-visas, ewr, air-canada, canadian-residents

Has anyone recently flown from Toronto to Mumbai via Newark on an itinerary sold by Air Canada during covid (United operates the leg from Newark to Mumbai and air Canada code shares that leg)? Does India’s air bubble agreement allow it? Does United allow boarding? How about the return on the same path? I am a Canadian permanent resident living in Toronto with Indian passport and a US B2 visa trying to go home.

I can see [here](https://www.civilaviation.gov.in/en/about-air-transport-bubbles) that any Indian National with valid USA visa can take Air India or US carriers. It doesn’t say that travel has to end/start in the US (onward allowed only to/from South America or Africa) as it says with many other countries.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the pandemic is now over